# What could be causing SqlConnection.Close() to take over a second to execute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf, sqlconnection

I have websites that are calling a WCF service, which in turn uses a `SqlConnection`. It always closes the `SqlConnection`, but in some cases it can take 1-3 seconds for the `Close()` statement to execute.

My understanding is that when you use instances of `SqlConnection` in websites that they use connection pooling, and I assumed the same was true of WCF but I don't know for sure. Actually, I thought that so long as the connection string is the same, it pools it regardless of what kind of application is using it.

So what could possibly be causing the `Close()` statement to take so long?

Comment: It might be waiting for the command to finish before closing. Are you bringing back a lot of data?

Comment: @OlaEkdahl Actually, right after I wrote this question I was able to find another post about that. In this case it is in fact not going through the entire result set, and adding a call to cancel the command did help. It still isn't what I would consider 'fast' even though so I'm still wondering why it isn't immediate but it's definitely better.

Comment: `SqlConnection.Close()` does only return the connection to the pool, but that's not an instantaneous operation even if there is no work pending on the connection. The connection is reset as part of the pool return (you can see this as an `exec sp_reset_connection` call in SQL Profiler). Normally this call is very fast, but if (say) your machine or your network is experiencing lag, `Close` can take time.

Comment: Is it possible there's an open transaction on the connection, so that it has to be rolled back?